# !db_connect - or die which is better

Tags: php, security

really quick question

please look at the following example

```
$dbConnect = mysql_connect($host , $username , $password) or die ("BIT OF A PROBLEM PLEASE COME BACK LATER");
```

is this a good way to do it or should I maybe use

```
$dbConnect = mysql_connect($host , $username , $password);
    if(!$dbConnect)
    {
        echo "COULD NOT CONNECT !!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "CONNECTED !!";
    }
```

If you could explain which way is best it would be a great help too.

also to add I have error_reporting(0); set

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is 2000-times more preferable to the first.  In the first method all the user will see is a blank page with the text "BIT OF A PROBLEM..." - not very user friendly.

With the second method you could do whatever you like, such as send an automated e-mail to support staff while re-directing users to a nicely presented error page telling them you've been notified of the problem and working on it etc.  If you have a second server you could also try connecting to that one as well before giving up completely.

Comment: So as security issue there is no better or worse way to do that.

Comment: As far as security goes, neither way is better or worse, it's purely cosmetic.  Remember to set display_errors to OFF in your php.ini, otherwise if mysql_connect does fail, PHP will plaster your connection details in a "warning" message across the browser - NOT what you want!

Comment: On the other hand, if there is nothing meaningful that the app can do if connection fails, dying is practical and secure.

Comment: @bugspy.net - it depends on the app's purpose. If it's put in front of users, I would never use die().  Actually I'd never use it anyway, and always redirect to another page.  That way if someone inadvertently switches display_errors back on, there's less chance of it leaking info.